# Using MySQL SUM Function Within Table to Populate Column

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to populate a column with the sum of some of the other columns in a table. When I try:

`UPDATE table SET sum_field = other_field1;`

there is no issue, but when I try:

`UPDATE table SET sum_field = SUM(other_field1 + other_field2 + other_field3);`

I get a syntax error.

Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `SUM` here, just take the sum using the addition operator:

```
UPDATE table
SET sum_field = other_field1 + other_field2 + other_field3;
```

The reason your current update is failing is that `SUM` is an *aggregate* function in SQL.  You were telling MySQL to update the `sum_field` from each *record* to the sum of the three columns from the entire *table*.

By the way, it might make more sense for you to add a generated column to your existing table:

```
ALTER TABLE table
ADD COLUMN sum_field INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (other_field1 + other_field2 + other_field3)
```